# Вектор выкидывает исключение

Tags: c++, исключения, vector, вектор, векторы

Почему эта прога выкидывает исключение???

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int,char**) 
{
    vector<char> delims = {",", "."};  
    cout << delims[0];
}
```

Comment: какое исключение? где выкидывает? может тут попытка добавить два символа `{',', '.'};`

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так `char` же! Не `char*`!!

```
vector<char> delims = {',', '.'};
```

Comment: а причом тут исключение? terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

Comment: @karina Вам просто не повезло. У вас вектор символов, а вы передали строки. Строки являются массивами `char`ов, и автоматически превращаются в указатели на свои первые элементы. Компилятор посчитал, что эти два указателя - на начало и на конец диапазона, из которого надо копировать символы в вектор. А эти указатели мало того что указывают на разные массивы (уже некорректно), так еще и похоже первая строка оказалась с бОльшим адресом, чем вторая - вектор совсем смутился.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Visual C++ просто не компилирует этот код.

Comment: @Harry, уточнить лучше:  Не `const char*`!!